# "government by two persons" is to "diarchy" as "government by simple majority" is to what?

Tags: word-request

As far as I know, the government by

- two persons is called "diarchy,"
- three persons is called "triarchy,"
- many persons is called "polyarchy."

So, my question is, is there a word to define the government by the simple majority of persons?

It's worth noting that "democracy" is not the word I'm looking for because such a word, as far as I know, defines a complex concept not based *only* on the majority criterion.

Comment: Actually, the more usual term for government by two persons is [diarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diarchy).

Comment: I believe this would much better belong to Politics.se - or if anything, English.se - not really a Learners' level of question...

Comment: @SF I concur - but I don't think we have migration ability yet.

Answer (score 2):

[Majority](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/majority) is the word which means  **Larger number of things or people.**

> 1.the greater part or number; the number larger than half the total ( opposed to minority ): the majority of the population.
>
> 2.
>   a number of voters or votes, jurors, or others in agreement, constituting more than half of the total number.
>
> 3.
>   the amount by which the greater number, as of votes, surpasses the remainder ( distinguished from plurality ).
>
> 4.
>   the party or faction with the majority vote: The Democratic party is the majority.
>
> 5.
>   the state or time of being of full legal age: to attain one's majority.

There is a doctrine which follows majority of people as the ultimate decision. It is known as [Majority Rule](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/majority%2Brule?q=majority+rule).

A system which follows majority rule is known as [Majority System](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Majority+System).

A Government which follows Majority System is known as [Majority Government](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majority_government).

Comment: Majority does not mean "maximum number"; the maximum number is larger than a majority. The rest of your bullet points are correct.

Comment: @MarkBeadles, Thanks for the rectification. Would edit the answer in no time.

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia, [**polyarchy**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyarchy) is in fact the word you're looking for:

> In modern political science, the term **polyarchy** (Greek: poly many, arkhe rule) was introduced by Robert A. Dahl, now emeritus professor at Yale University, to describe a form of government in which power is vested in three or more persons. This form of government was first implemented in the United States and was gradually adopted by many other countries. According to Dahl, the fundamental democratic principle is that when it comes to binding collective decisions, each person in a political community is entitled to be given equal consideration to their interests. A polyarchy is a nation-state that has certain procedures that are necessary conditions for following the democratic principle.

Wikipedia further suggests that the proper term for government by more than one person is [**Polycracy**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polycracy).